# Why wont it compile negative number in list

Tags: java, list, set

it keep on getting me an error of illegal character. rearranges
the list’s elements into sorted ascending order, as well as removing all duplicate values from the list

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Excerice_11point5{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Set<Integer> tal = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        tal.add(7);
        tal.add(4);
        tal.add(–9);
        tal.add(4);
        tal.add(15);
        tal.add(8);
        tal.add(27);
        tal.add(7);
        tal.add(11);
        tal.add(–5);
        tal.add(32);
        tal.add(–9);
        tal.add(–9);

        sortAndRemoveDuplicates(tal);

    }
    public static void sortAndRemoveDuplicates(Set<Integer> tal){
        System.out.println(tal);
    }   
}
```

Comment: By the way, if you are already using a Set, then don't worry about duplicate values.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that the negative symbol (-) *is* a simple dash ? Have you copied/pasted this from (say) a Word document or Excel spreadsheet and copied a symbol that looks like a standard hyphen but isn't ?

You can inspect what you've got in your file by using [od](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_od.htm), but perhaps the simplest thing to do is retype the dashes.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use a `–` but a normal `-` when writing Java code. The difference is subtle. You used the `endash` character which looks almost the same but really is different.

This often happens when word processors autoreplace `-` by `–` or `—`.

Comment: Was going to correct you by calling it an em dash, but I see that en dash actually exists.  I learned something new today, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. You use not `-` operation, but strange symbol `–` instead of it.